# Can someone die from pain?

Tags: pain

I'm a CNA and I just got home from a very long day at work. I just started this job and I got hurt at work last night which made me wonder **can enough pain cause death** (without suicide)**?**

I think the answer is yes, but I'd like to know how/why.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can go into [shock](http://www.livescience.com/36945-shock-causes-symptoms-treatments.html) from bleeding, emotional disturbance, a heart disorder, and/or a blood infection. It causes not enough oxygenated blood to get to important organs in your body and if it isn't treated it's normally fatal.

I would think that enough pain could cause a large emotional disturbance which could result in shock.

Comment: Please give some solid references. I do think this would be possible though, especially if one has a weak heart; as an increased heart rate from pain could stress it.

Comment: Pain and shock are completely different things. Your answer needs references and clarification.